# Refactoring slightly different sequences of if statements

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a class in which I've found the following code snippet, in 3 different methods:

```
if (errCode == IN_ERR_CONST_1)
    throw new CustomException(OutErrorType.TYPE_A);
if (errCode == IN_ERR_CONST_2)
    throw new CustomException(OutErrorType.TYPE_A);
...
if (errCode == IN_ERR_CONST_9)
    throw new CustomException(OutErrorType.TYPE_B);
if (errCode == IN_ERR_CONST_10)
    throw new CustomException(OutErrorType.TYPE_B);
```

I initially thought of refactoring this by putting it all in a method and using some map, but then I realized that the ifs sequence was slightly different in each method, that is one of the n ifs statements is followed by a different block of code.

For example, in one method we would have:

```
if (errCode == IN_ERR_CONST_2)
    throw new CustomException(OutErrorType.TYPE_A);
```

and in the second method we would have:

```
if (errCode == IN_ERR_CONST_2)
    throw new CustomException(OutErrorType.TYPE_B);
```

while everything else is the same.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map for this like (for example, in class constructors):

```
   Map<String,OutErrorType> errorsMap = new HashMap<>();
   errorsMap.put(IN_ERR_CONST_1, OutErrorType.TYPE_A);

  ...
```

Then you can just use

```
OutErrorType outErrorType = errorsMap.get(errCode);
if(outErrorType != null) {
    throw new CustomException(outErrorType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do some strategy like this;

```
enum OutErrorType {

    TYPE_A, TYPE_B, UNKOWN_ERROR;

    private static Map<Integer, OutErrorType> MAP;
    static {
        MAP = new HashMap<>();
        MAP.put(IN_ERR_CONST_1, OutErrorType.TYPE_A);
        MAP.put(IN_ERR_CONST_2, OutErrorType.TYPE_A);
        MAP.put(IN_ERR_CONST_9, OutErrorType.TYPE_B);
        MAP.put(IN_ERR_CONST_10, OutErrorType.TYPE_B);
    }

    public static OutErrorType getTypeByCode(int errCode) {
        return MAP.getOrDefault(errCode, OutErrorType.UNKOWN_ERROR);
    }
}
```

You will consolidate all configs on this enum and can get without any if